# Indexing through a string to grab all the letters after numbers appear

Tags: python

```
city = 'water1234atlantaga'
state = 'ga'
```

How would I be able to grab the part of the string that appears after the numbers?

Comment: You could do that with a million ways. What code did you try ?

Comment: regex is your friend here. import re then use the .sub() method to remove everything before and including the numbers

Comment: There are many ways you can do this with regex: `sub()`, lookaround expressions, etc.

Comment: Try to be more specific about the format of the initial string. The way it is right now and given the question you are asking. I would do it this way `print(re.split('\d+', 'water1234atlantaga')[-1])`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
import re

city = 'water1234atlantaga'

res=re.findall(r"(?<=\d)[^\d]+", city)

print(res)
```

Outputs:

```py
['atlantaga']
```

In essence:

`[^\d]+` matches 1, or more non-digit character

`(?<=\d)` indicates, that it has to be preceded by a digit (without returning the digit itself)

The whole thing will return all the matched non-digit strings - so e.g. if you would have `a1b2c` it would return `['b', 'c']` if you don't care about second and following just take `res[0]`.